# Remember menu actives element

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, nav

I'm creating a menu for my site and I don't know how to keep the selected item checked.
At the moment it keeps bouncing back to the first one.

```css
nav {
    margin: 27px auto 0;

    position: relative;
    width: 590px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
}
nav a {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav .animation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 110px;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}
nav .start-about, a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 110px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-family: 'Cherry Swash',cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
}

span {
    color: #2BD6B4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_menu.css">
    </head>
    <body> 
      <nav>
        <a href="#">test</a>
        <a href="#1">foo1</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me to keep the clicked menu item selected. I don't want to have to use javascript. Is there a way to do this? I read something about an 'active' element.

Edit: Since @hackerfrosch thinks that the whole thing is easier with js, I tried that. But I don't know how I can assign a class to the buttons via js in my case. Can I specify the color that the button should have, since each button has a different color?

Comment: Store state of your menu in localstorage

Comment: I don't know how to do that and actually would have preferred to save it in a class.

Comment: **How Long** do you want to Store it? Just till the page gets reloaded, till the user closes your website or so that it gets stored even when the user closes the browser and revisits your site another time?

Comment: It should be shown until I click another button in the menu. If the tab or browser is closed, the information does not need to be saved.

Comment: Unfortunately, there‘s no way to solve this without js. But it’s not that complicated. You can just add a class to the selected element and style the element with css

Comment: Ok, too bad. Thanks for the answer anyway, I'll try it with js later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a little further and completely remade the menu. The design is roughly the same and it works entirely without Javascript.

```css
.slide-toggle{
    display: none;
}

.slide-menu{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-menu label{
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.slide-menu label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-menu label span{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 15px 15px;
    color: white;
}

.slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #415a75;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.slider .bar{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.slide-menu label, .slider .bar {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.slide-menu .slide-toggle + label{
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide-menu #slide-item-1:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 0; background: #1abc9c }
.slide-menu #slide-item-2:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 25%; background: #e74c3c }
.slide-menu #slide-item-3:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 50%; background: #3498db }
.slide-menu #slide-item-4:checked ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 75%; background: #9b59b6 }

.slide-menu #slide-item-1:hover ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 0; background: #1abc9c }
.slide-menu #slide-item-2:hover ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 25%; background: #e74c3c }
.slide-menu #slide-item-3:hover ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 50%; background: #3498db }
.slide-menu #slide-item-4:hover ~ .slider .bar{ margin-left: 75%; background: #9b59b6 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_menu.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="slide-menu">
            <input onclick="location.href='#1'" type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-1" class="slide-toggle" checked/>
            <label for="slide-item-1"><span>Home</span></label>

            <input onclick="location.href='#2'" type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-2" class="slide-toggle"/>
            <label for="slide-item-2"><span>About</span></label>

            <input onclick="location.href='#3'" type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-3" class="slide-toggle"/>
            <label for="slide-item-3"><span>Folio</span></label>

            <input onclick="location.href='#4'" type="radio" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-4" class="slide-toggle"/>
            <label for="slide-item-4"><span>Contact</span></label>

            <div class="animation start-home"></div>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```